# Smooth transition across mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to learn a method for creating smooth transitions between components of an object while keeping the geometric integrity of the two pieces.
[image: 1]

I would not like to alter the general shape of the ring or hook part, but am curious what ways there are to smoothly transition parts of an object so that I may create better looking models.

[hook.blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/34a6b80bc4e940b9909a6a240ccfe719)

Comment: you first need to boolean then give some corrections in Edit mode: remove doubles, join vertices, etc... maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I have added the .blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should simplify your object to make it easier to work, select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*:

[image]

Here is what you get (set the parameters in the *Operator* box), as long as it doesn't change your shape it's better to work low-poly imho:

[image]

Then boolean the 2 objects:

[image]

It gives bad topology:

[image]

But you're going to work on it with the knife tool, join, dissolve edges and vertices, etc:

[image]

Now you can give your object a *Subdivision Surface* etc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help with learning how to smoothly transition. Thanks for the tip about working in low-poly as well.

Comment: Yes, work low-poly as much as possible, it makes things easier, only apply the Subdivision Surface if necessary, and always keep a low-poly version